# First epoch takes way way longer than the others

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am training two CNN's on Google Colab: VGG and InceptionV3.
I've got 10 classes, with 11614 training samples and 2884 validation samples.

These are the codes used for instantiating the models:
a) VGG (~250,000 free parameters):

```py
    base_model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                             input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in base_model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten(name='flatten', input_shape=base_model.output_shape)(x) 
    x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
```

b) InceptionV3 (~20,000 free parameters):

```py
    base_model = keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3 (include_top=False,
                      weights='imagenet', input_shape=(299, 299, 3))

    for layer in base_model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) 
    x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
```

I trained on 5 epochs each, just to see the results, and I found out something very odd: The first epoch takes about an **hour** to complete, the rest about **3 minutes** each.

These are the outputs from the training:
a) VGG:

```py
    Epoch 1/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 6260s 17s/step - loss: 1.2611 - acc: 0.6735 - val_loss: 0.9555 - val_acc: 0.7712
    Epoch 2/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 159s 440ms/step - loss: 0.9351 - acc: 0.7800 - val_loss: 1.1295 - val_acc: 0.7903
    Epoch 3/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 156s 431ms/step - loss: 0.8751 - acc: 0.8033 - val_loss: 0.8300 - val_acc: 0.8219
    Epoch 4/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 155s 429ms/step - loss: 0.8482 - acc: 0.8075 - val_loss: 0.7436 - val_acc: 0.8524
    Epoch 5/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 155s 429ms/step - loss: 0.8031 - acc: 0.8263 - val_loss: 0.9327 - val_acc: 0.7970
```

b) InceptionV3:

```py
    Epoch 1/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 4052s 11s/step - loss: 1.3590 - acc: 0.5542 - val_loss: 1.3469 - val_acc: 0.5455
    Epoch 2/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 249s 687ms/step - loss: 0.8921 - acc: 0.7115 - val_loss: 1.3225 - val_acc: 0.5519
    Epoch 3/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 241s 667ms/step - loss: 0.7938 - acc: 0.7347 - val_loss: 1.1960 - val_acc: 0.5999
    Epoch 4/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 239s 660ms/step - loss: 0.7589 - acc: 0.7416 - val_loss: 1.2979 - val_acc: 0.5593
    Epoch 5/5
    362/362 [==============================] - 237s 654ms/step - loss: 0.7252 - acc: 0.7505 - val_loss: 1.3122 - val_acc: 0.5565
```

It is fairly obvious to say that Inception suddenly starts overfitting, although in my opinion this shouldn't be happening: there are less parameters to be trained, and I even added a dropout layer.

Any ideas why there's a significant difference in the epoch times?

Edit: Apparently I didn't include the version of Inception instantiation where I add a dense layer, but when I was training, there was one.

Comment: I  believe that the long time taken for the first epoch may be due to the initialization of model parameters. Also, 5 epochs may be too low to decide if the model is overfitting or not

Comment: I am not sure how scalable this solution is, but what worked for me was setting workers =  1 and use_multiprocessing=False in the fit_generate method. Also, I will try with more epochs and will report with results.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I think It's due to the fact that the first iteration is also used to build the computational graph and optimize it, but I'm still looking forward for more info/solutions